# Creating gzipped Sitemap in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sitemap

In Laravel, I want to create a gzipped sitemap on the fly, with the [maximum number of URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/large-sitemaps) that Google allows (50,000), within the [maximum file size](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap#:%7E:text=Sitemap%20size%20limits%3A%20All%20formats,your%20sitemap%20into%20multiple%20sitemaps.) (50 MB). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your URLs are *very*, *very* long, you'll likely need to make a file size calculation ahead of time to limit the number of records returned, but otherwise, do this to serve a sitemap with the maximum number of URLs:

Add to `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/records-{page_number}.xml.gz', [SitemapController::class, 'records'])
```

Create a new controller.

```bash
php artisan make:controller SitemapController
```

In the sitemap controller's `records` function:

```php
public function records(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->route()->parameters, [
        'page_number' => 'required|numeric|min:1|max:1000000'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return false;
    }

    $page_number = $request->route('page_number');

    $urls = [];

    // Google's URL limit for a single sitemap.
    $links_per_page = 50000;

    $last_id = DB::connection('your_connection')
                 ->table('your_table')
                 ->select('id')
                 ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                 ->limit(1)
                 ->pluck('id')
                 ->first();

    $cursor = $last_id - ($links_per_page * ($page_number - 1)) + 1;

    $records = DB::connection('your_connection')
                 ->table('your_table')
                 ->select(['id', 'page_slug'])
                 ->where('id', '<', $cursor)
                 ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                 ->limit($links_per_page)
                 ->get();

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $urls[] = config('app.url') . '/' . $record->page_slug;
    }

    // In testing, the Spatie sitemap package is too slow for this.
    $xml_content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n" .
                    '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" ' .
                    'xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ' .
                    'xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" ' .
                    'xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">' . "\n";

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $xml_content .= '<url><loc>'  . $url . '</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1.0</priority></url>' . "\n";
    }

    $xml_content .= '</urlset>';

    $gzip_compressed_xml_content = gzencode($xml_content, 9);

    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($gzip_compressed_xml_content) {
        echo $gzip_compressed_xml_content;
    }, 'records-' . $page_number . '.xml.gz');
}
```

*Note: the sitemap shows the most recent records first based on the `id` column.*

---

If you have many of these sitemaps with 50,000 URLs (up to 500), you should have a sitemap index.

Install `spatie/laravel-sitemap`:

```bash
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap
```

Add to routes:

```php
Route::get('/sitemap.xml', [SitemapController::class, 'index']);
```

Add to index function:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapIndex;
use Spatie\Sitemap\Tags\Sitemap as SitemapTag;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $sitemap_index = SitemapIndex::create();

    // 500 is the total limit of sitemaps in a sitemap index for Google.
    // https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/large-sitemaps
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 500; $i++) {
        $sitemap_index->add(SitemapTag::create('/records-' . $i . '.xml.gz')->setLastModificationDate(Carbon::yesterday()));
    }

    return $sitemap_index->toResponse($request);
}
```